# YouTube Data API v3 - get playlist order by latest updated time

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

In YouTube Data API v3, how can I retrieve the list of playlist order by latest updated time of videos in playlist. For example, three playlists { A, B, C } and each playlist contains 10 videos published at 1 year ago, 1 weeks ago, and 1 day ago, respectively (published time of videos in playlist, not published time of playlist). Then, I want to get the playlist ordered by latest videos = { C, B, A }. I have so many playlists, so get all playlists/videos and manual sorting is inefficient.

Another time-consuming way is to get latest videos and re-build playlists, but Videos do not contain playlistId. So, "get playlist A -> get videos in playlist A" is possible, but "get video A -> get playlists with video A" is not possible.

I checked [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) with { type:playlist, order:date }, but the result is ordered by published time of playlist, not the videos in the playlist.
I checked [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), the result is ordered by published time of playlists and it does not contain "order" parameter in query.

Please let me know any good ideas!

Comment: For your rebuild process you can do: For a playlist A , get all videos from that list and create a new list with all videos plus the new video(s).So the new list A' has the **publishedAt** field updated. This way every time that you have a new video in a list , that list will have the **publishedAt** updated.